# Delete everything between two characters in each line

Tags: regex, text, notepad++

For each line, how to delete everything between the **5th** occurrence of `"` and the **last** occurrence of `.`, noninclusive? The section that is to be deleted  contain any number and variable pattern of problematic (for regex) characters such as `:/\()[]|.,?"`, etc.

For example:

```
"123456789","xyxyxy","DELETE///.T.H.I.S.aaa"
"123","abc","DELETE."\T.H.I.S\[.]".1234"

"123456789","xyxyxy",".aaa"
"123","abc",".1234"
```

I keep failing (possibly because of incorrect escaping of problematic characters?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex:
`((?:[^"\n]*"){5})(.*)(\..*)$`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mnrHaY/2)

**Explanation:**

- `^` - asserts the start of the string
- `(?:[^"\n]*")` - matches 0+ occurrences of any character which is neither a `"` nor a newline character greedily followed by a `"`
- `{5}` - repeats the above match 5 times. Everything matched so far is captured in group 1.
- `(.*)` - match and capture 0+ occurrences of any character **greedily** but not a newline character. This is stored is group2. It is this part which will later be removed/deleted. Greedy match because we now want to reach the last `.`. We can reach there by backtracking(in the next step)
- `(\..*)` - match a dot followed by 0+ occurrences of any character but a newline character and store in group 3
- `$` - asserts the end of the string

**Output:**

Before Replacing:

[image]

After Replacing:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure it is compatible with notepad++, but this regex should do he job:

```
((?:"[^"]*){4}").*(\..*)
```

with replacement:

```
\1\2
```

Example and explanation: https://regex101.com/r/yBuUOj/3

Comment: thanks! your initial version (now deleted) is working fine: `((?:"[^"]*){4}")[^"]*\.(.*)` (it deletes the last `.`, but i can live with that. (***your current version `((?:"[^"]*){4}").*\.(.*)` makes some mis-recognition)

Comment: sorry i did some copy&paste mess between here and regex101